# FileSystemWatcher - will I get a buffer overflow or similar?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I need to watch a folder (on a network share) and be notified when a filename changes and the file is moved to a sub directory (all one event). This event occurs maybe twice a day. I will have multiple `FileSystemWatchers` to watch multiple folders for the same thing.

However, `FileSystemWatcher` is notoriously bad for missing events and I cannot have that happen. I've tried replicating the environment and it seems to work however I don't know whether that's because I am doing something in particular.

If I watch for only `OnRenamed` events, am I still likely to have issues or can I be sure that I won't miss events?

Comment: What does you question have to do with its title? I don't see anything regarding a buffer overflow.

Comment: With the default buffer size, the absolute worst case is that it can store 15 events.  More typical is around 30 or 40, it depends on the length of the file path names.  This will of course not get put to test on a rename event that occurs twice a day.

Comment: @Hans Passant Do all `FileSystemWatcher`s use the same buffer out of interest?

Comment: No, every watcher has its own buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a correctly working network, you should not have any error related to missing events, but you should be aware that a simple hiccup on you network will render your FileSystemWatcher monitoring useless.

A momentary drop in the connection to the network share will trigger an Error in your FileSystemWatcher and even if the connection will be reestablished, the FileSystemWatcher will no longer receive any notification.

This is a sligtly adapted example found on MSDN

```
static void Main()
{
    // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = @"\\yourserver\yourshare";
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    // Only watch text files.
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

    // Add handler for errors.
    watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    // Wait for the user to quit the program.
    Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
    while(Console.Read()!='q');
}
private static void OnError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
{
    //  Show that an error has been detected.
    Console.WriteLine("The FileSystemWatcher has detected an error");

    //  Give more information if the error is due to an internal buffer overflow.
    Type t = e.GetException().GetType();
    Console.WriteLine(("The file system watcher experienced an error of type: " + 
                       t.ToString() + " with message=" + e.GetException().Message));
}
```

If you try to start this console application and then disable your network connection, you will see the Win32Exception, but if you do it again, no more error event will be seen by the running FileSystemWatcher